# Getting many to many fields of many to many association in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have two levels of many to many associations in django. A player can belong to one or many teams. And a team can play one or many tournaments. Given a player i want to know in which all tournaments he has played.

Following is the simplified model:

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)


class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    tournaments_played = models.ManyToManyField(Tournament)

class Player(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    belongs_to_team = models.ManyToManyField(Team)
```

In my views i tried the following:

```
pl = Player.objects.get(player_name = "Andrew Flintoff")
ts = pl.belongs_to_team()
```

## this gives me more than one team, now for each of the team i want to know which tournaments they have played.

```
qs_list = []
for t in ts:
   team_qs = Team.objects.get(team_name = t)
   tourn = team_qs.tournaments_played.all() 
   qs_list.append(tourn)
```

and then in my context i can pass the queryset list `qs_list`. Is there a better/simpler way of doing it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 p1_tournaments = Tournament.objects.filter(team__player=p1)
```

There's an implicit lookup created for every reverse foreign key or m2m field. It's either the lowercased model class or the `related_name` argument, if specified.

So, essentially, that filter says get the tournaments related to teams that are related to the player, `p1`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i don't  understand the following things: team__player = p1. where p1 is some object of Player. How does "team" (team__player) without being referenced to anything does things right? or have you missed somethng?

Comment: Thanks! so in case in my models had i done this way class Player(model.Models):     belongs_to_team = models.ManyToManyField(Team, related_name="alpha") then doing Tournaments.objects.filter(team__alpha = p1) would have given me the desired stuff. Please let me know if i am wright.

Comment: No, it would be `alpha__player`. The `related_name` on `Team` would replace the default lookup of `team`. FYI the double-underscore (`__`) causes a traversal: it looks for the next lookup on the `Team` model now instead of `Tournament`. So you could also do something like `team__team_name` to lookup Tournaments associate with a specific team, by the team's name.

Comment: Or you could even combine steps and do `team__player__player_name='Andrew Flintoff'`.